# LINQ: What is the LinqDataSource equivalent of "adapter.Fill(ds)"?

Tags: asp.net, linq, adapter, data-binding, linqdatasource

I am trying to use LinqDataSource instead of using the SQL dataset.

Currently, if I want to update my GridView, I just declare a

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

then I

```
adapter.Fill(ds);
GridView.DataSource = ds;
GridView.DataBind();
```

What is the equivalent code using LinqDataSource to update my GridView? Thanks.

Comment: Calling GridView.DataBind() again doesn't refresh the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume you using datacontext then this example might help you

```
  using(MyDataContext ctx = new MyDataContext(){
  this.MyGridView.DataSource = from something in ctx.Somethings where something.SomeProperty == someValue select something;
  this.MyGridView.DataBind();
}
```